# validation in form not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I don't know what im doing wrong, i have a form and using this function to check if the input is empty...what Iam trying to do is to highlight the field by adding a class to the text field...but if i add this line

> name.addClass("empty");

to the function, the function dont work

```
function register()
{
    if(document.myForma.userid.value == '')
    {
        name = $("#userid");
        document.myForma.userid.focus(); 
        $("#empty").html("This field is required")
        name.addClass("empty");
        return false;
    }   
}
```

Comment: How doesn't it work? Do you get some kind of an error?

Comment: `name = $("#userid");`  - note "$"

Comment: @CacheStaheli I don't get any error..i look like it skips the function

Comment: I believe you left off a dollar sign: `$("#userid");`.

Comment: @Igor still not working

Comment: So do you actually have an element with that id?

Comment: Could you share the html part too?

Comment: I feel Pure Javascript does not give any error sometimes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare your `name` variable as local, or use a different name for it, - global `window.name` already exists and is not changeable.

```js
console.log(name);

function register() {
  if (document.myForma.userid.value == '') {
    var name = $("#userid");
    document.myForma.userid.focus();
    $("#empty").html("This field is required");
    name.addClass("empty");
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="myForma" name="myForma" onsubmit="return register();">
  <input id="userid" type="text" />
  <div id="empty"></div>
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: +1, what I was in process of posting,  One more reason NOT to use global variables. I also like the added semi-colon on the line prior to the newly added one.

Comment: Perfect,  i forgot to put 'var' in form of name...thank you